How to center multiple line equations in the align environment automatically if it does not contain "&"
I always use the align environment even if it contains only one line, because I am too lazy to predict how long it will be before writing the equation.
Also, I use "&" only when I want to align multiple lines nicely.
When I do not need to align nicely, I want to omit "&" and I want the align environment behave like the gather environment.
Is there any setting?

never use align for single line equations it will produce sub-optimal vertical  space. use \begin{equation}

There must be a reason why the authors of amsmath endeavored to provide different environments for different purposes.

Thank you for comments. Then I want to know if I can define any environment such that if it contains only one line then it works as equation, else if it contains multiple lines without & then it woks as gather, else it works as align.

It is theoretically possible, but why?  the aim of document markup is to explicitly mark up the document structure, why avoid doing that and rely on some fragile heuristics to guess the intended structure?

@DavidCarlisle
It is often the case that I try to write an equation on one line for now, and if it is too long, I break the line.
Also, sometimes I cannot decide whether to use between align and gather until I output a PDF and see how it looks.
I generally use gather for expressions, except when I want to align =, etc., but sometimes it looks better to align with a certain symbol, in which case I use align.
Thus it is convenient if I can use such an environment.
Also, I don't think it's fragile because you can just judge it by whether or not it contains "\" or &, but what do you t

checking for & and \\  is possible but not entirely trivial as you need to (for example) skip over any arrays/matrices so you have to just check the top level and not check inside any environments so you need to count matching begin/end pairs (or hook into the existing amsmath gathering macros or ....) and you have to hook that in in a way that doesn't break extensions such as mathtools. As I say, it's possible, but I don't think I'd do it.

Thank you. I understand that it is certainly not easy. I wanted to be born into a world where align makes equations centered instead of right-aligned when it does not contain &...

@Salangidae but you could say the same about tabular that it should revert to a normal paragraph if it is a single column (technically this is an almost identical request)

Thank you, I see why align is right-aligned...
